# In Magento, I am change the product visibility of configurable child product but not work Properly

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.5

Here is my block code

```
$filteredProducts = $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $parentID)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => "configurable"));

    foreach($filteredProducts as $_product) {
        $_children = $_product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($_product);
        foreach ($_children as $child){
            if ($child->getID()) {
                $array =  [ 
                    1 => 'Not Visible Individually',
                    2 => 'Catalog',
                    3 => 'Search',
                    4 => 'Catalog, Search'
                ];

                $currentValue = array_search("Search",$array);
                $child->setVisibility($currentValue);
                $child->save();
            }
            echo "<pre>";
            var_dump($child->debug());
        }
    }
```

This works only frontend and not apply in product grids.

Comment: Where is this code executed ? What do you mean by "product grids", is it the admin grids "Catalog > Products" ?

Comment: I am execute this code in configurable view page. Its work in frontend, means that search of that product but When I check Product grid list its not change "Not Visible Individually" to "Search".

Comment: Can you try to reindex all the indexes, and then flush the cache ? Can you also check that your cron are running properly ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$filteredProducts = $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $parentID)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => "configurable"));

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();


    foreach($filteredProducts as $_product) {
        $_children = $_product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($_product);
        foreach ($_children as $child){
            if ($child->getID()) {

                $child_product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($child->getID());

                $array =  [ 
                    1 => 'Not Visible Individually',
                    2 => 'Catalog',
                    3 => 'Search',
                    4 => 'Catalog, Search'
                ];

                $currentValue = array_search("Search",$array);
                $child_product->setVisibility($currentValue);
                $child_product->setStoreId(1);
                $child_product->setWebsiteIds(array(1));
                $child_product->save();
            }
            echo "<pre>";
            var_dump($child->debug());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not change in product list grid

Comment: Using ObjectManager is not recommended in most cases. Plus, here loading the product again is redundant because you already have the product object in the `$child` variable. It also seems that you use an undefined variable (`$product`).

Comment: Have you any solution please give here. Thanks

Comment: code updated..   Check after run indexer command....
php bin/magento indexer:reindex